# MongoDB and Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I'm trying to use MongoDB in a Java Web Service.

As suggested in Mongo tutorial I should have a MongoClient, let it be dbInstance, connection pool and call dbinstance to get a connection to the database, which is in localhost.

So this is what I have:

```
private static MongoClient dbInstance = null;

public static DB getDBInstance() {
    if (dbInstance == null) {
        try {
            dbInstance = new MongoClient();
            registerShutdownHook();
        }
        catch (Exception exc) {
            System.out.println("Exception");
        }
    }
    return dbInstance.getDB("SAED");
}
```

What I don't understand is how I can understand if I'm connected to the DB, because, also il mongo isn't working (by starting mongod service) it doesn't throw exceptions.

And another question, I have multiple thread calling Class.getDBInstance, should I synchronize it, and if yes, how can I do that?

Comment: Are you using Spring in your Java application? If so, you can define a MongoTemplate and inject that anywhere you require connectivity to do stuff (save documents, search collections and such). Have a look at SpringData.

Comment: No, I'm not using frameworks.

Comment: is that something you're unable to change? They're designed to make your world a lot less painful ;)

Comment: What framework should i use?

Comment: Depends on your situation I suppose, however Spring is a widely adopted choice. You can see an example of Spring data/MongoTemplate usage in a little REST app I created here : https://github.com/jameselsey/restful-mongo

Comment: The objective is to create a SOAP based web service

Answer (score 0):

You will be thrown an exception when the mongo is not running while you try to connect.

When you do the MongoClient(), it will always look for in the localhost for port 27017 to connect.  You can also parameterize this to connect to a different machine and/or port.

You can read more in depth details about this at [Mongo Documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Tutorial#JavaTutorial-MakingAConnection).

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
// or
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" );
// or
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
```

Regarding your synchronization question,
Yes, you can synchronize at a block level to make it better instead of at the method level.

Comment: The matter is that it doesn't throw exceptions! It should but it doesn't!

Comment: But worst then this is that is I do MongoClient("randomIP") it doesn't throw exceptions o.O

Comment: @litiales You could raise a Jira with them then.

Comment: Raise a ticket with mongo db

Comment: The main reason that MongoClient constructors don't throw exceptions if the mongod instance is not available is that the mongo server can go down at any time during the life of the client application, so applications have to deal with server failure every place that the server is accessed, not just when the MongoClient constructor is called.